# Java How To Crate masking phone number

Tags: java

how do you make a masking string of the first 4 digits and the last 3 digits, apart from that in masking.. as an example: 0813*****129 I've tried to do like this

```
public static String maskingPhoneNumber(String value) {
        return value.replaceAll("[^\\d\\+628|08]", "").replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "X");
    }
```

and **result XXXXXXXX6600 not expected**

expected the below :

[image: expected this picture]

Comment: You can use `substring`, no need to involve regex.

Comment: By the way, why didn't you wait for your [other (now deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667820/java-how-to-crate-masking-phone-number) to be reopened instead of going through the trouble of rewriting it again with a different user?

Comment: Use [StringUtils.overlay()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#overlay-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-int-)

Comment: I don't get it: What is the input string for the method that should give you the expected result? It's clearly not `"0813*****129"` as this does neither end in 6600 nor in 664, and also does not start with +6287. Please add details about inputs you give, results you would expect and actual results. (2 or 3 complete test cases wouldn't hurt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex based approach here:

```java
String input = "081312345129";
String masked = input.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{4})\\d(?=\\d{3})", "*");
System.out.println(masked);  // 0813*****129
```

The regex used here says to match any number for which:

- `(?<=\d{4})` we can look behind and see at least 4 numbers (i.e. retain first 4 numbers)
- `(?=\d{3})` we can look ahead and see at least 3 numbers (i.e. keep last 3 numbers)